"Предназначен для..." или "Используется в...". Как правильнее?
Как правильнее?

Патрон 12-го калибра предназначен для охотничьего ружья и самозарядных дробовиков.

или

Патрон 12-го калибра используется в охотничьем ружье и самозарядных дробовиках.


Правильно:
Патрон 12-го калибра используется в охотничьем ружье и самозарядных дробовиках.
Пояснение

Из Википедии

12 калибр (12 gauge) — в настоящее время самый распространённый гладкоствольный калибр. Используется для спортивно-тренировочной и развлекательной стрельбы, самообороны и охоты.
 Наибольшее распространение получили патроны, снаряжённые 
 картечью и снаряжённые дробью. Также выпускаются пулевые 
 патроны. Охотники и спортсмены нередко самостоятельно 
 переснаряжают патроны.


Соответственно, речь идет не о предназначении патрона 12 калибра , а о его разном применении.

